# Grub can't recognize Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot, grub

I previously had Windows 7 installed alongside Ubuntu 14.04. I recently upgraded to Windows 10 which removed the grub bootloader. So, I used `boot-repair` from a live USB to restore grub. But now grub only shows Ubuntu as a boot option. I've searched the internet for a solution and I've tried many to no avail.

Even adding a `menuentry` in the `40_custom` file did not work for me.

You can see the Boot Info Summary [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12793731/). Please help!

Comment: Have you run grub-install when booted in Ubuntu?